# Why is my question broken?

Tags: bug

It appears [my question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/45883/11762) is broken, at least for me in IE9. All other questions appear fine.

[image]

I've tried refreshing the page and restrating my browser, but no luck. Is this happening to anyone else?

Comment: Not seeing the problem in Google Chrome Version 24.0.1312.57 m.

Comment: Just managed to load the page without the problem, but when I refreshed, the problem came back.

Comment: Looks fine in my IE 8, latest Chrome, and FF 15.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Internet Explorer is notorious for an aggressive caching policy, which means it will happily cache an invalid or incomplete response from a website and use that.

Many SE pages are built using AJAX calls, where the content is requested separately from the "framework". This is most commonly seen when you click the "An edit has been made" or "There's a new answer" banners. But these requests for new data can fail. With IE, such a failed request can be cached and used in preference to a new request. In your case it looks like the "framework" has been corrupted.

Try a forced refresh of the page (usually this is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>), or *in extremis* delete all cached content — perhaps restricting this action as much as possible — and then get the page again.

Comment: Must've been some bad caching - looks good today.